# Using the insert function in a class

Tags: python, insert, tkinter, calculator

I was having trouble with this code and the insert function. Im just trying to make a (very) simple calculator and i was getting error messages when i used the insert function.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
import tkinter as tk
global square
global multiply
global divide
global minus
global add
global finalnum
square = 0
multiply = 0
divide = 0
minus = 0
add = 0
finalnum = 0

class Calculator(tk.Tk):# class for calculator
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.wm_title('Calculate!')# changes widow title
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=150, height=100)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='9', command=self.nine).grid(row=3, column=4)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='8', command=self.eight).grid(row=3, column=3)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='7', command=self.seven).grid(row=3, column=2)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='6', command=self.six).grid(row=4, column=4)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='5', command=self.five).grid(row=4, column=3)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='4', command=self.four).grid(row=4, column=2)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='3', command=self.three).grid(row=5, column=4)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='2', command=self.two).grid(row=5, column=3)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='1', command=self.one).grid(row=5, column=2)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='0', command=self.zero).grid(row=6, column=3, ipady =10)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='+', command=self.add).grid(row=9, column=3)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='-', command=self.minus).grid(row=9, column=2)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='÷', command=self.divide).grid(row=10, column=2)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='x', command=self.multiply).grid(row=10, column=3)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='=', command=self.equals).grid(row=11, column=3)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='√', command=self.root).grid(row=9, column=4)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=3, height=1, text='^', command=self.square).grid(row=10, column=4)


    def zero(self):
        global number1
        number1 = 0
        num1 = 1
        if num1 == 1:
            global num2
            num2 = 0
    def one(self):
        global number1
        number1 = 1
        num1 = 1
        if num1 == 1:
            global num2
            num2 = 1
    def two(self):
        global number1
        number1 = 2
        num1 = 1
        if num1 == 1:
            global num2
            num2 = 2
    def three(self):
        global number1
        number1 = 3
        num1 = 1
        if num1 == 1:
            global num2
            num2 = 3
        print(num1, num2)
    def four(self):
        global number1
        number1 = 4
        num1 = 1
        if num1 == 1:
            global num2
            num2 = 4
    def five(self):
        global number1
        number1 = 5
        num1 = 1
        if num1 == 1:
            global num2
            num2 = 5
    def six(self):
        global number1
        number1 = 6
        num1 = 1
        if num1 == 1:
            global num2
            num2 = 6
    def seven(self):
        global number1
        number1 = 7
        num1 = 1
        if num1 == 1:
            global num2
            num2 = 7
    def eight(self):
        global number1
        number1 = 8
        num1 = 1
        if num1 == 1:
            global num2
            num2 = 8
    def nine(self):
        global number1
        number1 = 9
        num1 = 1
        if num1 == 1:
            global num2
            num2 = 9

    def add(self):
        add = 1

    def minus(self):
        minus = 1

    def divide(self):
        divide = 1

    def multiply(self):
        multiply = 1

    def square(self):
        square = 1

    def root(self):
        if num1 == 0:
            finalnum = number1**.5
        else:
            error = 1

    def equals(self):
        if add == 1:
            finalnum = number1 + num2
        elif minus == 1:
            finalnum = number1 - num2
        elif divide == 1:
            finalnum = number1 / num2
        elif multiply == 1:
            finalnum = number1 * num2
        elif square == 1:
            finalnum = number1 ** num2
        self.entry.insert(END, finalnum)        


calculator = Calculator()
```

Comment: Nobody will read this whole mess of code to figure out where you did something wrong. Narrow it down to a minimal example and post the complete error tracebacks if you want help. And just for the record: `global` declarations need to be in the functions where you _use_ the global variables, they don't do anything at the global scope - your `add`, `minus`, `divide` etc. functions won't work this way.

Comment: Also, there is no need to have all those `global` statements at the top.  Removing them altogether will not impact the code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to search for the error message you're getting, you would see that this problem is addressed many times on stackoverflow.

The problem is this line:

```
self.entry = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4)
```

In python, if you do `foo=bar().baz()`, foo will be given the value of the .baz() function. Therefore, when you do `self.entry = tk.Entry(...).grid(...)`, self.entry will be given the result of `.grid(...)`. grid always returns None, therefore self.entry will be None. And therefore, when you try to call `self.entry.insert` you will get the error `NoneType object has no attribute 'insert'`

Here's a hint on how you could have figured this out yourself:

The first rule of debugging is to assume the error message is telling the truth. In this case it's saying that a "NoneType" object doesn't have the method you think it does. You should know that this object should be of some type other than "NoneType", so ask yourself "if the variable isn't what I think it is, what is it?".

The simplest thing you can do is to print out the object, and python will tell you what it is. So, just *before* the line of code that is throwing the error, add the line `print self.entry`. You'll instantly find out that it is set to `None`.

Again, ask yourself "why?". You then need to look back through your code to see where you set the variable. When you find where you set it, put the print statement immediately after. You'll then find out either a) it's being set properly (and in this case it is *not*), or b) it is *not* being set properly. If the answer is (a), you have more research to figure out where and why it's changing. In the case of (b), you know know *where* the bug is happening. You simply need to ask one more time "why?".

You may not be aware that grid returns None, so you still might not know the solution to your problem. Now, however, you can ask a much better question because you've done a little research, and you know exactly where the root of the problem is.